# Get files deleted between git revisions

Tags: linux, git, bash

I need to create a list with files which was added, changed and deleted between two git revisions. List with added/changed files I can get by this command:

```
git diff --name-only $from_revision $to_revision > "changes.txt"
```

it gives a simple and clean list in changes.txt like this:

```
addons/tiny_mce/plugins/image/plugin.min.org.js
addons/webrtc/adapter-latest.js
templates/standard/style/review.css
```

My question is how can I generate a similar list with files **deleted** between two commits?

OS: Ubuntu 16.04, git: version 1.9

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`--diff-filter`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#git-diff---diff-filterACDMRTUXB82308203) and filter only deleted files with `D` :

```
git diff --name-only --diff-filter=D  $from_revision $to_revision
```

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I need